# How to completely disable Fedora surveying my browser e-mail activity

Tags: fedora, firefox, privacy

I have Fedora release 33, and after the last update, I was absolutely freaked when I checked my email from Firefox 85 (running in a private mode), and the Fedora application that informs about updates, informed that I received an e-mail to the website that I checked on Firefox.

That's an outrageous invasion of privacy. I do not want at all my OS to know anything about any e-mail or activity I do on a browser. Those are independent layers. I do not want any surveying or logging of any access to a browser e-mail.

I do not want my OS to know at all what e-mail service I use.

I guess that Firefox has to have a service to inform the OS, and the OS has to have a service to receive the information, to log it, and to show the message on screen.
There is no point in running Firefox in private mode, when it reports his activity to be logged by the OS.

I need to know how to disable all of it: Firefox reporting it to the OS, and the OS taking and logging that information.

If not possible, it is enough justification to replace both Firefox and Fedora.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're talking about notifications. You may (inadvertedly) have allowed notifications on the email site that you use. This is easily fixed by going to the email website and clicking on the little icon to the left of the URL in the address bar. That will show you the permissions given to the site (it will say "Send Notifications"). I'm not turning this into an answer as the question is borderline off topic and since I'm not 100% certain it's what your issue is (as you also mentioned "logging" without further explanation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your title wording is very misleading. The notifications aren't coming from anything going out and collecting information. It's coming from something *listening for intentional notification broadcasts from applications*.

None of this is going anywhere off of your machine. GNOME Shell is just showing you that Firefox has sent a notification — just like it might show you a notification from the separate GNOME Software app that updates are available, or a notification from Terminal that a long-running process is complete.

The notification application — or other applications, for that matter — have no access to anything from the email website or anything else in Firefox *that wasn't intentionally sent*.

If you don't want Firefox to send notifications for a specific site (or at all!), you can turn that off in the preferences. See [Web Push notifications in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/push-notifications-firefox) for details.

Notifications aren't logged long term by anything by default in Fedora Workstation, although that might actually be a nice feature. You can see what notifications go past by running this in a terminal window:

```
dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'"
```

To generate a test message, try `notify-send "Don't panic."` in a different window.

It is worth noting that one reason Fedora has moved to Wayland by default rather than X11 is stronger separation between applications, and Flatpak will give even more. But if you want *really* strong separation, take a look at [Qubes](https://www.qubes-os.org/), an OS based on Fedora which uses virtualization technology to run applications in isolated "compartments".

Comment: As an addendum: running your browser in private mode only tells the browser to not remember what you're doing, and gives some light isolation from the rest of your browser session. It doesn't shield you from, for example, your ISP tracking DNS requests.